# Is there way to find a record by searching in array type value in firebase angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, angular6, angular2-services

I have a array type key in firebase collection which store a lot of ids and I have to find the value by searching one in that array type value so is there any where clause query in firebase for angular 6 that can help me.

This is how the data stored in db
[image]

How can I get the data where event_id is OivLjBcdEIdpvhSv27sk?

Please check the image and respond if there any thing regarding that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to do with the list of ids?

Comment: how can I get the data where event id is OivLjBcdEIdpvhSv27sk?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firestore, then you can use a query on the collection with the `array-contains`.

```
const userCollection = db.collection("users");
const result = userCollection.where("event_id", "array-contains", "OivLjBcdEIdpvhSv27sk")
```

Check documentation here: [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)